# Как посылать сообщения с UDP broadcast сервера и прослушивать их на подключенном к нему клиенте?

Tags: c#, сеть, ip, сетевое-программирование

Всем привет. Хочу сделать так, чтобы мой сервер мог посылать свои сообщения на широковещательный канал. Клиенты в свою очередь к этому UPD-серверу должны быть подключены и получали от него пакеты.

Как я понимаю это всё должно быть просто (Сторона сервера):

- Сначала я создаю instance UdpClient:

```
    // Тут я просто указываю порт. Серверу не нужно знать свой IP, чтобы к нему 
    // могли подсоединяться клиенты (как раз-таки клиентам и нужно)
    UdpClient SenderListener = new UdpClient(11000);
    SenderListener.EnableBroadcast = true;

    // вместо Broadcast пробовал "172.16.75.255" 
    IPEndPoint remoteEndPoint = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Broadcast, 11000);
```

- Далее я рассылаю сообщения в broadcast

```
    while (true)
    {
        var bytes = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(Console.ReadLine());
        SenderListener.Send(bytes, bytes.Length, remoteEndPoint);
    }
```

Сторона Клиента:

- Тут я просто инициализирую клиента и в конструкторе указываю какой сервер нужно прослушивать:

```
    UdpClient client = new UdpClient("127.0.0.1", 11000);
    var data = new byte[256];

    IPEndPoint ep = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Any, 11000);
```

- Собственно жду, пока broadcast сервер начнёт вещать:

```
    while (true)
    {
        data = client.Receive(ref ep);
        Console.WriteLine(Encoding.ASCII.GetString(data));
    }
```

Уже второй день мучаюсь с этой казалось бы лёгкой вещью. С теоретической т.з. я хорошо понимаю о чём тут идёт речь, но почему я просто не могу прослушать то, что посылает сервер клиентам?

Comment: Когда вы слушаете на 127.0.0.1 вы никак не можете услышать пакеты посланные в сеть 172.16... потому как это разные сети !

Comment: Слушайте лучше IPAddress.Any, если хотите слышать все интерфейсы

Comment: это аналогичный 255.255.255.255 (broadcast) ip. Я это указал на случай, если кто предложит этот вариант

Comment: @Mike Нет, мне нужно слушать именно этот Udp сервер. Как я могу услышать то что посылает интересующий меня сервер, если я не знаю его IP?

Comment: Слушатель udp слушает свой порт, а не конкретного отправителя. И слышит от все, что на него посылают, а посылать может кто угодно, хоть на броадкаст, хоть на конкретный ip этой машины. Если бы вы знали ip отправителя, то вам надо было бы фильтровать получаемые пакеты самостоятельно, проверяя от кого они пришли. Если же вы и ip сервера не знаете, то у вас проблема... невозможно быть уверенным, что вам что то говорит Иван Иванович, не зная его голоса и как он выглядит

Comment: И кстати, а что в том варианте кода, который у вас с Any и отправкой на IPAddress.Broadcast вы что нибудь слышате ? И запускаете вы это на одной машине или на разных. И если они разные, то как они между собой соединены.

Comment: @Mike у меня всё на одной машине

Comment: @Mike Я вот сейчас пытаюсь понять что вы хотите донести. Не могли бы вы ответом написать клиента, который может прослушивать мой локальный 
udp сервер?

Comment: Почитал я тут про UdpClicent ... У вас  все напутано ... `new UdpClient(11000)` создает слушающую сторону, т.е. клиента. А вот `new UdpClient("255.255.255.255", 11000)` создает сокет, который будет посылать пакеты на указанный адрес и порт

Comment: вот пример гугл дал https://gist.github.com/zmilojko/5055246